# use JS array stored in user meta - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I am storing an JS array in user meta. 
Then retrieving that array I am  using below code

```
<input type="hidden" name= "my_array" id= "my_array" 
   value="<?php echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), "ARRAY_NAME",false);?>" />
```

In console it  shows me like this

```
<input id="my_array" type="hidden" value="Array" name="my_array">
```

Now I want to use this array in my JS code so I did this

```
var my_data = $("#my_array").val();
     console.log("confffi");
    console.log(my_data );
    console.log("confffi");
```

Output is

```
confffi

"Array"

confffi
```

How to get my JS array and use it in JS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your function get_user_meta returns an array (at least from the output of your code)
If that is the case, try this:

```
var my_data = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode(get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), "ARRAY_NAME",false));?>');
 console.log("confffi");
console.log(my_data );
console.log("confffi");
```

Comment: `<input id="config" type="hidden" 607"}}]"="" 607","step4_price":"11="" 607","step2_price":"9664","estimated_price":"11="" 3":[{"type":"gardero","section_prod_id":"5976"}],"extradata":{"calculating_price":"11607.75","step1_price":"0","price_step1":"11="" 2":{"profiler":"5991","profile_color":"silver","door_data":{"section1":{"door_panel_id":"5799","door_sub_panels_id":["5940","5940","5940","5940"]},"section2":{"door_panel_id":"5792","door_sub_panels_id":["5940","5940"]}}},"step="" 1":{"width":"2500","height":"2500","depth":"1000","chosen_vegg":"1"},"step="" step="" value="[{" name="config">`

Comment: HTML shows like above and console shows this `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data while reading object contents at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data`

Comment: You may want to do `addslashes(json_encode(get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), "ARRAY_NAME",false));)`, or just use single quotes for your html

e.g. `<input type='hidden' name= 'my_array' id='my_array' 
   value='<?php //phpcode here ?>'/>`

Comment: can you see my js array I posted in my question

Comment: The fact is that you don't need to set it in a hidden field. Let me edit the answer to reflect this...

Comment: Yes you  were right single quotes did the trick .. you are genious. can you please tell me when to do jason_encode or decode and when to parse.

Comment: basically, when you want to send php objects to the client side, you should always `json_encode()` (PHP). And if you want to convert a json String to javascript object on the client side, you should use `JSON.parse()` (Javascript)

Comment: great thanks sir . i wanted to upvote your answer but due to low reputation i am unable to do it. I will do it when I am allowed to . You are genius man !!

Comment: I always get confused with JS array / objects and all work arounds with it\

Comment: Just keep coding. All the concepts will catch on with time. And also be active on Stackoverflow. You'll meet some people who'll disrespect you because they have grown in knowledge, past where you are now, but just ignore them, and keep bringing your questions here. You are helping newbies like yourself without knowing it. Cheers man. I wish you an interesting and rewarding journey in the field of software development!

Comment: Thanks A lot for encouraging Sir !